# How to remove line feed in CSV download using PHPExcel

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, csv, phpexcel

I have the data with new lines in database.

for example:

```
Testing Habit
Testing Habit Testing Habit
Testing Habit Testing Habit Testing Habit
```

**I want to show the data with space instead of new line in csv downloaded file.**

Now I am using PHPExcel library to download csv file.

Here is my code:

```
$output_file_name = "myfile";
$output_file = $output_file_name . ".csv";
$output_file = mb_convert_encoding($output_file, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setCellValue("A1", '"'.str_replace(chr(10), '&nbsp;', $info['ModelName']['habits']).'"');

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$output_file.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_CSV($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->setDelimiter(',');
$objWriter->setEnclosure('');
$objWriter->setLineEnding("\r\n");
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter->setUseBOM(true);

$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

How to remove the line feed?

Comment: Make sure that you're using `"\n"` for the linebreaks from the database, and `"\r"` for your csv file line endings

Comment: You can construct a string with all the text you want (with a loop) and then print it to your sheet insted of use set cell value of a single one

Comment: Can I use the replace function in [fields] of $this->ModelName->find method when retrieve the data from database. for example : `replace(replace(replace(COLUMNNAME%,chr(13)||chr(10),' '),chr(13),' '),chr(10),' ')`